# Arrange all the words in a list in alphabetical order in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, alphabetical

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void alpha_sorting(vector<string>& a);
void swap_function(vector<string>& x,int& l);
string alpha_least(vector<string>& list,int& idx);
int min_word_index(string& min,vector<string>& listed);

int main(){
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("words.txt");
    if(!infile.is_open()){
        cout << "Could not open the input file" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    vector<string> words;
    string temp;
    while(infile >> temp){
        words.push_back(temp);
    }
    sort_words_alphabetically(words);
    cout << "Those words in alphabetical order are " << endl;

    return 0;
}

void alpha_sorting(vector<string>& a){
    int index = 0;
    while(index < a.size()){
        swap_min_to_top(a, index);
        index++;
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < a.size();i++){
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}

void swap_function(vector<string>& x,int& l){
    string temporary;
    temporary = x[l];
    wrdx[loc] = minimum_word(x, l);
    int min_idx = min_word_index(x[l], x);
    x[min_idx] = temporary;
}

string alpha_least(vector<string>& list,int& idx){
    string temp = list[idx];
    for(int i = idx;i < list.size();i++){
        if(list[i] < temp){
            temp = list[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

int min_word_index(string& min,vector<string>& listed){
    for(int i = 0;i < listed.size();i++){
        if(min == listed[i]){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Hi all,

In short, the assignment requires us to read words from a file and arrange them all in alphabetical order and display them to the screen.

The assignment specifically prohibits the use of c++ functions like sort etc. and expects us to create our own algorithm to arrange this vector.

My algorithm finds the minimum (the one that comes in the alphabet) string (using the '<' operator) in the list and then places it at the start of the vector, updates the index by 1 and repeats the process till the list is ordered. My only problem is that as others have informed me, using vectors filled with strings is always messy, my code doesn't display the correct answer, (as if the vectors aren't being updated or are undergoing any operations for that matter).

Can someone please find what is wrong with my code?

Comment: In order to sort a vector you *swap* elements. At no point in your algorithm do you have two indices that you are swapping. <addition> Looks like you're searching halfway through the swapping. Try to make that function first *search* what it wants to swap, and only then do the swap.

Comment: @dascandy I made the swap_min_to_top function for that. is there something wrong in it?

Comment: If this is not homework, have you tried `std::sort`?

Comment: @Afr0: Try to make a simple program that runs this on a vector with 2 or 3 elements in the wrong order. Then get that to work. Then, expand on it by adding more test calls. Also, look at the state of your program with a debugger (say, visual studio).

Comment: @dascandy, I appreciate the advice, I had a chronological error as pointed out by theAlias. And to add further onto the idea of this being homework. This actually was one of my assignments in first year that I did poorly in, so it was always something I intended to finish. I have also added a function that can enable the user to search for any word entered in that directory by string manipulation. I do have only one question about that: Is the methodology used for sorting the vector and implementing the search function efficient enough?

Comment: You're using insertion sort, O(n^2) on average. Perhaps you are. There are order-of-size more efficient functions, but they are more complicated and have a higher base overhead. Just keep in mind that you can replace your entire program with std::sort and std::binary_search. Both are in C++98.

Answer (score 2):

After a quick look here's one issue,
In `swap_min_to_top` you do
`wrdx[loc] = minimum_word(wrdx, loc);`
AND THEN
`int min_idx = min_word_index(wrdx[loc], wrdx);` 
This will make your `min_idx` always equal to `loc` (because you just assigned it)

You may want `min_word_index` to process from 1+idx, instead of zero

Comment: Given that he admitted this to be homework I didn't want to point that out too explicitly - he has some learning to do in finding out why it didn't work, and then what it does do. Also, basic learning about debugging, debuggers and unit tests.

Comment: Thank you very much @theAlias. The program now works without any problems !

Answer (score -1):

With a classic bubble sort you must go on. Thanks to Wikipedia. Please give the answers rights to user Christophe BoueeCinq . ccgousset@gmail.com

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;

    int flag=0;
    string tmp="";
    int index=0;
    int k=0;

    int main()
    {
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("words.txt");
        if(!infile.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Could not open the input file" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        vector<string> words;
        string temp;
        while(infile >> temp)
        {
            words.push_back(temp);
            cout <<temp<<endl;
        }
        cout <<"-----"<<endl;

        int inx=0;
        int i=0;
        int change=0;
        int j=0;

        i =words.size(); // longueur(t)
        change = 1;
        while ((i>0) && (change==1))
        {
            change = 0;
            for (j=1; j<words.size()-1; j++) //        pour j allant de 1 à i-1 pas 1 faire
            {
                if  (words[j] > words[j + 1])
                {
                    tmp = words[j];
                    words[j] = words[j+1];
                    words[j+1] = tmp;
                    change = 1;
                }
            } //       fin pour
            i = i - 1;
            // fin tant que
        }

        _getch();


      for (j=0; j<words.size(); j++)
      cout <<"xx "<<words[j]<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Gitaar, first i am in anonymous way the one way to participe to the life of site. My real mail ccgousset@gmail.com is out of time (it seems to me ...). Two why is applied to my code this negativ sanction ? This code is running and is the only real good reponse between lot of reponses. Certainly your not an idiot. Amicalement Christophe.

Comment: "The aim of an argument or discussion should not be victory, but progress" - Joseph Joubert who's paraphrasing Pierre de Coubertin in another plaisant comment " Only defeat is two daughters mother's"

Comment: Hi, I see you removed that offending comment so I removed mine that addressed that. Regarding the down-vote (which was not mine): you (and 'we') seem to be stumbling over a language barrier. *"Please give the answers rights to user Christophe B*******q . c*******t@gmail.com"* *sounds/looks* to a lot of people as a question (that expects answers to that question to be sent to an email-address). On SO, questions must be posted as questions (not as answers) and comments/remarks to questions and answers are left in comments (not email).

Comment: Also, a lot of users downvote what is called 'code-only' answers. "*With a classic bubble sort you must go on"* is not very clear. Does that mean that the OP (person who asked the question) must put the after his code or must he replace (part of) his code with the bubble sort code from wikipedia, or ... ? There seems no further explanation, until one looks at the comments in your code. However these comments are in French and therefore unreadable to a lot of 'us'. Also, on SO, we 'require' English only (I tried running your comments through google translate to improve your answer, but ....

Comment: ... that didn't render understandable results). All three of the above are common reasons for people to downvote. I'm posting these comments to try and help you understand why you probably got the downvote and help you understand how SO 'works'. Now, I can not undo someone else's downvote, but if you could add some extra information and attempt to translate the French parts to English (to an understandable level), then I'll upvote it (I'd even be happy to help you 'polish' some wording/grammar if I'd at least understand what you are/were trying to say/write). Good luck!!